# discordjs/voice adapterCreator is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a play command for my discord bot, but it gives me this error :

> TypeError: adapterCreator is not a function

Here is my code:

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

module.exports ={
    name:'play',
    description:'aaaaaaaaaaaam',
    execute(message, args){
        const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, generateDependencyReport } = require('@discordjs/voice');
        const url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NevKVKbCNy4&ab_channel=NTDM'
        const stream = ytdl(url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
        const player = createAudioPlayer();
        const resource = createAudioResource(stream);
        const GuildMember = message.author.id;
        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: GuildMember.voiceChannel,
            guildId: message.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: message.channel.guild.voiceAdatperCreator
        })
        connection.subscribe(player);
        player.play(resource);
        
        console.log(generateDependencyReport());
        
    }
}
```

Comment: you made a typo: `message.channel.guild.voiceAdatperCreator` (p and t and inversed)

Comment: Now it doesn't give an error, but doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your `joinVoiceChannel()`:

```js
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: message.channelId,
    guildId: message.guildId,
    adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
});
```

Your `const GuildMember = message.author.id` is actually a **string**, in which case you cannot do `GuildMember.voiceChannel`.

`message.guildId` & `message.channelId` are shorthands to getting the respective ids.

I suggest reading the voice documentation [here](https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-connections.html#playing-audio):

Comment: Well, it doesn't return an error anymore but he doesn't do anything, it doesn't connect to the channel.

Comment: Are you in a voice channel?  `joinVoiceChannel()` requires the command executor to be in one.

Comment: Yes, I am currently in one

Comment: Should be an external problem in your codebase that isn't showcased here. Other than the `joinVoiceChannel()` function, your code is pretty much correct.